# How to catch Errors arising before the message enters the scope block in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, catch-block

Biztalk Error

I am having an Biztalk Orchestration,In It I am having a Biztalk Scope and Catch Block in order to catch errors arising inside the scope.I am able to catch error in it whenever there is any error in the corresponding scope shape.

But problem arises when the orchestration fails at the begining of its processing, i.e before entering the scope shape(this happens when there are some special characters in the xml received).
I am stuck on this! plz help!!

Answer (score 2):

If Biztalk can't determine the message type (usually identifying the xmlns#root), then the message will be suspended and your intended target orchestration won't be touched.

I'm not sure what you mean by special characters though. If the document isn't valid XML, then you either need to ask the source system / partner to fix it, or otherwise would need a custom pipeline to scrub data in the receive port.

If however you mean something like Byte Order Markers, BizTalk should be able to parse these. Check that you have selected XmlReceivePipeline on the port maybe?

Comment: Can neone tell me..? which excepion to use 4 catching the Invalid input xml error inside my catch (Exception handler) Block.

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the same (failing) message into BizTalk without using an orchestration, and only using the same pipeline, do you get the same exception? Is the scope block the first thing in your orchestration?

Comment: No scope block is not the first thing, i have one recieve shape before the scope otherwise (if i take the recieve shape inside the scope block) it gives an error that "use of unconstructed mesage", in the catch block.

Comment: what about when you don't use an orchestration to receive and send the same, failing message?